# What is the purpose of the ability to bounty a meta question?

Tags: discussion, bounty, meta

I have recently decided to bounty a meta question of mine. This got me thinking about bounties on meta questions.

What is the purpose of them? In my case, only the  moderators and high rep'd users could help me, and for them my humble offering of 50 reputation was a drop in the bucket.

So, could someone please explain to me why meta questions should be bountied? Can you give a specific example? Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: You cannot add bounties on per-site metas but only on Meta Stack Overflow. So this may be off topic here.

Comment: High-rep users cannot help you with the the question you are referring to, not at all. Only Stack Exchange employees can.

Comment: Yes, but high rep users can help by drawing the attention of the SE employees toward the question.

Comment: I don't really agree. Don't really understand the logic in that but that might be just me.

Comment: OK. I was hoping that the high rep'd users had friends in high places and therefore could contact the moderators. That was my logic.

Comment: This should probably be saked on AskUbuntu Meta Meta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a moot point on SE 2.0 site metas like this one. Bounties aren't possible on these child meta sites at all.

Bounties are acceptable on Meta Stack Overflow largely for the reasons you mentioned - to draw more attention to the question. I've had mixed results with it myself. Generally I find that most high-rep users, moderators, and employees try to keep up with the questions already, though some do fall through the cracks once in a while.

Generally speaking, if you want moderator attention, flagging a question is the best way to go.